# Extjs number field width is incorrect

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

When a number field (or date field) is added to a form panel, the width of the number field is not adjusted to match the panel width.  Here is a simple example showing that the text field is adjusted to fit the available space, but the number field is not.  See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc0a/xZFPX/1/).

It looks like a bug in the Extjs picker layout.  Does anyone have a work-around?

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/tags/extjs-4.2.1/release/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/tags/extjs-4.2.1/release/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.namespace('E2cc.settings');
E2cc.settings.getString = function(s) { return s; }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Ext.onReady(function () {
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    width: 200,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Text',
        border: 3,
        style: {
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderStyle: 'solid',
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Number',
        border: 3,
        style: {
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderStyle: 'solid'
        },
        name: 'date'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
});
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: You gave the field a fixed width of `90`, however the `fieldLabel` is configured by default to be larger than that. Change the `labelWidth`.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: oops, code posted didn't match fiddle.  fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't explain why it is rendered differently than a normal textefield, but a good pratice in extjs is to specify the width of your elements and not let extjs layout compute it for you. Add anchor: '100%' to your numberfield and it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to defined some same values to all the fields you must define it in the dedatults property.

see [your example](http://jsfiddle.net/lisssb/3ZVUR/) modified

`Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
         width: 200,
        defaults : {
            width: 200,
            labelWidth : 70
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Text',
            border: 3,
            style: {
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderStyle: 'solid',
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Number',
            border: 3,
            style: {
                borderColor: 'red',
                borderStyle: 'solid'
            },
            name: 'date'
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });`